# Cors error on loading local css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, cors, content-security-policy

When using script and link tags to load in js/css files (from a vue project), the browser refuses to load them in.
These are the errors:

```
Access to script at 'http://www.example.com/js/app.7f934f5b.js' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This error occurs in both the latest Safari on iOS and macOS, and on the latest developer version of Chrome.

As the tags are generated by `yarn build`, which uses the vue cli to build the production version, I have no control over how the tags are generated.

Below is the index.html with the content-security-policy meta tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="<%= BASE_URL %>">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src self; script-src self 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:; style-src self 'unsafe-inline' http: https:; img-src self data: http: https:; font-src self http: https:; connect-src http: https: ws:">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico"/>
    <link href="fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Application title</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <strong>
        We're sorry but Vue.js doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled.
        Please enable it to continue.
    </strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has a suggestion on how to solve this problem, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are **not the same origin**.

To avoid this problem, pick one to be canonical and redirect all other requests to it.

Comment: I redirected everything to `www.example.com`, which fixed the issue for me after reloading the apache server. Thank you!